# Swift Mapkit Received memory warning

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, didreceivememorywarning

Im developing ipad app and looking memory using good all viewcontrollers but my `MapDetailViewController` gives me `Received memory warning` how can i resolve it .

All viewcontrollers use my app max `34.MB` memory but `MapDetailViewController` using `100 MB` More. My codes under below `what is wrong` ?

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapDetailViewController: UIViewController,MKMapViewDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet var mapView:MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mapArea: DesignableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameSales: DesignableLabel!


    var showmapListcomming = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Show Map

        let myString: String = showmapListcomming
        var myStringArr = myString.componentsSeparatedByString(",")

        nameSales.text = myStringArr[0]

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        let latitude:CLLocationDegrees = (myStringArr[1] as NSString).doubleValue
        let longitude:CLLocationDegrees = (myStringArr[2] as NSString).doubleValue
        let latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 150
        let lonDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 150
        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)
        let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)

        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: false)

        annotation.coordinate = location
        annotation.title = myStringArr[0]
        annotation.subtitle = "User"
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

 }

    // MARK: - MKMapViewDelegate methods

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        let annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView()
        return annotationView
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Comment: Is the memory increasing as it is sitting there, or is it stable if you aren't touching anything?

Comment: @TroyT when opened 34 MB later when i touching 94 mb and when i touch more goes 100 MB more

Comment: @TroyT also i do fast go back viewcontroller go map again, again again shows 160 MB

Comment: How many annotations do you have? Try not using annotations and see what happens.

Comment: @TroyT u see codes there only have 1

Comment: Right, sorry. As I said, try not adding annotations.

Comment: @TroyT not adding annotations ? so my map views purpose show user location on map i think must be good answer for this problem.

Comment: Just try removing annotations to determine if the annotations are causing the memory problem.

Comment: @TroyT how can i do ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103773/discussion-between-troyt-and-swiftdeveloper).

Comment: Map view is known as memory consuming, 100MB sounds all right. It handles memory warning itself quite well already.